# How to serialize multiple forms and access the submitted one's data using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, jquery-validate, each

I want to make a generic form validation script where I would compare a form's existing data with the data that is submitted. The validation would fail if the submitted data is **NOT** different from that which exists on page load.

The problem is if one has multiple forms and one wants to validate the existing data for just a single form. Here's a JSFiddle that's seems pretty close to working but still isn't: http://jsfiddle.net/aMUNh/33/

**I think the problem with this JSFiddle is the `$.each(function)` and setting up the `existingData` JSON object.**

HTML:

```
<form id="form1">
<input name='form1name1' value='form1value1'>
<input name='form1name2' value='form1value2'>
<input id="1" type="submit" value='submit'>
</form>

<form id="form2">
<input name='form2name1' value='form2value1'>
<input name='form2name2' value='form2value2'>
<input id="2" type="submit" value='submit'>
</form>
```

JS:

```
var existingData={}; //declaring the object to be cached
$("form").each(function(index){  
    existingData.id+=this.id;
    existingData.id.data+=$(this).serialize();
});
var id='form1';
document.write('existingData:'+existingData.id.data);

$('input [type=submit]').click(function(){
    var id='form'+this.id;
    var submittedData=$(this.form).serialize(); 
      if(submittedData==existingData.id.data){
      console.log('nothing changed');
      }
      else console.log('this form changed');       
});​
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is with the formatting of your data references; just use the form's `id`.  You need something like this:

```
var existingData = {}; //cached data
$('form').each(function(index){  
    existingData[this.id] = $(this).serialize();
});

$('form').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // don't really submit for testing
    var form = this;
    var submittedData = $(form).serialize(); 
    var originalData = existingData[form.id];
    if (submittedData == originalData)
        console.log('nothing changed');
    else 
        console.log('this form changed');       
});​
```

Comment: -@NRohler, thanks this looks great! Can i ask if you have a nice shortcut to access the `id` of the button which was clicked? I need to keep track of this so that's why I had  `click()` instead of `submit()`.

Comment: If you want to track `click`s, use `<input type="button" />` then programmatically `form.submit()`.  From the `click()` handler, use `var form = $(this).closest('form')[0];`